# How to authenticate user using column encryption of password as well as using password salt technique at business logic?

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, encryption, hash

I am facing a problem in creating a logic. I have two stored procedures: One creates user accounts by encrypting passwords and emails:

```
if (SELECT count([Email])FROM [Regs] where EncryptByAsymKey(AsymKey_ID('---encryption key----'),@email)=@email)=0
       begin 
       INSERT INTO [Regs]
           ([Password]
           ,[Email]) values (EncryptByAsymKey(AsymKey_ID('---encryption key----'),@password),EncryptByAsymKey(AsymKey_ID('---encryption key----'),@email));
           select @scopeIdentity = SCOPE_IDENTITY();
   --OTHER OPERATIONS--
```

and other authenticates user by accepting password and email and then decrypting both of them:

```
if @keyType=0 and (select count([UsrId])  FROM [Regs] where CONVERT(nvarchar(MAX), DECRYPTBYASYMKEY(ASYMKEY_ID('---encryption key----'), [Password], @enkey)) = @password and CONVERT(nvarchar(MAX), DECRYPTBYASYMKEY(ASYMKEY_ID('---encryption key----'), [Email], @enkey))= @key)>0
     begin
     select @userId= [UsrId],@username=[UserName],@uemail=CONVERT(nvarchar(MAX), DECRYPTBYASYMKEY(ASYMKEY_ID('---encryption key----'), [Email], @enkey)) FROM [Regs] where CONVERT(nvarchar(MAX), DECRYPTBYASYMKEY(ASYMKEY_ID('---encryption key----'), [Password], @enkey))=@password and CONVERT(nvarchar(MAX), DECRYPTBYASYMKEY(ASYMKEY_ID('---encryption key----'), [Email], @enkey))=@key;
    set @isvalidated=0;
    set @o_uid=@userid;
    set @o_username=@username;
    set @o_uemail=@uemail
     end
    --OTHER OPERATIONS--
```

`--OTHER OPERATIONS--` contains tasks like inserting, deleting or updating other tables when a user is created or authenticated. And this is where I face problem.

These two stored procedures are called by C# function `createUser()` and `authUser()`. I want that only one database connection should be made by each of these functions. That's why I wrote other operations in the same stored procedures. So that there will be one roundtrip to the database. This will save calls to database.

Now I want to implement password hashing or salt technique given here: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/425150/Beginners-guide-to-a-secure-way-of-storing-passwor.

This article shows how to hash the password in C# and send it to the database and then fetch it, take it's hash again and then compare it at C#. But the problem is that my comparison is done at stored procedure and then if it's correct the stored procedure will execute other operations. But I also want to hash password at C# so that even if database encryption is cracked, the hacker will need C# code to find out the real password(Even vice-versa is also secured). So please tell me how can I implement this technique without making any changes to my stored procedures?

Answer (score 0):

In 99.999999999% of cases, you want hashes for passwords so you cannot retrieve the original password. That means even if your database is compromised, passwords cannot be retrieved without significant computation effort.

If you're dead set on leaving it in SQL Server, I would stay away from using AES and take a look at [`HASHBYTES`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174415.aspx). Use `SHA2_256` or `SHA2_512` as the algorithm and salt the input as you seem to be doing already. But there are more more secure hashing functions like bcrypt or PBKDF2 which I don't think are implemented in SQL, and you would need to implement the password hashing at the business logic layer.

Once you've implemented your hashing method, you would hash the user input in the same manner you generated the user password hash. Then compared the hashed input value vs the stored hash in the database. If they match, the passwords match.

<sup>[More information about password hashing at Information Security Stack Exchange](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/211)</sup>